# link to a sample database for tests Oracle 11g express edition

Tags: sql, testing, oracle11g, relational-database

Could someone please provide me with a link to some database script (creation with values inserted), like the one used in W3C schools tutorials ?
 I want to use it to test some SQL scripts.

Comment: Like the ones in the tutorials you're looking at?  Or the exact ones in the tutorial you're looking at?  Oracle already ships with various sample schemas, `scott` and `hr` being two of the more popular.

Comment: do they come already installed with the 11g express edition version ? or I have to download their script ?

Comment: They come with the database.  There may be an option during the installation process to create the sample schemas or not-- there is during the installation of the full database but I don't recall that being an option during the XE install.

Comment: Well Thank you @JustinCave very much. I hope I will find these schemas after installation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend provided me with the following [link](https://code.google.com/p/northwindextended/) to google code, a project that aims at converting northwind database SQL code to be compatible with many DBMS.